# "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection"

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

have small problem here.
heres the code:

```
 using (LINKSEntitiesMaster LE = new LINKSEntitiesMaster())
            {

                Cache["ALLDB"] = LE;                   

            }

 internal void FilterDB(string ParentPageTitle, string ButtonName)


    {

        var ALLdb = (LINKSEntitiesMaster)Cache["ALLDB"];


        var x = ALLdb.MainTables.Where(s => s.Language == ParentPageTitle && s.ButtonName == ButtonName).Select(w => w.AllLinks).ToList();



        Links.DataSource = ALLdb;
        Links.DataBind();


}
```

the error is in the topic.
i save the filterd DB to a list,cant see why the connection closed...?

i been searching but could not fined an answer.

Comment: It disposed the second the using block ended, so your storing a disposed context in your cache.

Answer (score 1):

Connection is likely being closed since `LINKSEntitiesMaster LE = new LINKSEntitiesMaster()` is wrapped in a using statement. Once you code goes outside the `using` scope `LINKSEntitiesMaster` gets disposed.

Comment: So every function i need a connection i have to open it again?,i wanted to open one connection and store all the DB in a CACHE and than use it when i need

Comment: How can i sotre the DB otherwise? and use it without opening a connection?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at using some kind of ORM like EntityFramework. What kind of database are you connecting to?

Comment: SQL 2008 small DB with only 1 table on it

Comment: Your building a drawbridge over a tiny stream. Just create a new context each time and move on.

Comment: @MaxPetya You are right to be concerned about opening/closing a lot of connections.  But at the end of the day, if you are working with a database, you'll be doing a lot of these open/close operations.  Your job as a programmer is to streamline your process so that you minimize these open/closes, not just try to trick the system into leaving the connection open (which comes with another set of consequences--connection pool issues).

Comment: @Brian - He obviously *IS* using an ORM

Comment: @GarrisonNeely - Actually, no.. he is not right to be concerned.  EF does connection pooling and does not actually create new connections each time you create a new context.  It's very intelligent about managing connections.

Comment: @MystereMan - good point, my fingers were working faster than my brain :(